# Google Analytics as component for CakePHP

Tags: api, cakephp, plugins, components, google-analytics

Please tell me the components to work with Google Analytics, a CakePHP? Found much of everything, but it's outdated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Theres a recent plugin for Analytics (Google) on github: https://github.com/msadouni/cakephp-plugin-google-analytics updated in 2011!

Comment: Thanks for the link. This plugin is the easiest way to access GA data I have found and very Cake friendly.